# How i check Request from Mobile App or WEB

Tags: php, api, laravel

i need to check if the request came from a mobile App (Android or IOS) or WEB using **LAREVEL**.

I am using 
    `$value = \Request::header('Content-Type');`
and it returns

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So how i detect request origin?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this detection?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Using is simple , read the documentation.

```
$agent->is('Windows');
$agent->is('Firefox');
$agent->is('iPhone');
$agent->is('OS X');
```